4.1.0 Custom Normals In Cycles Have Weird Shadow Artifacts / Look Checkered

So, I have some custom split normals set up for a tuft of fur on a body. I used a data transfer and a vertex proximity weight modifier to blend the normals and make them appear seamless.
Here is what they look like in the viewport. As intended, smooth and appealing.

But when I enter render mode using Cycles, the custom split normals completely change.
They become checkered and display a wide range of artifacts.
This also happens with EEVEE.

I've searched online and looked all over Blender for a solution.
Some kind of setting that will preserve and prevent this from happening, but I haven't found anything.

I believe the geometry may just be too different from the surface represented by the normals. Normals just fake a surface direction, there must be at least approximate surface beneath them and this situation does not seem like it's enough. At least not enough for Cycles that needs to calculate realistic shadows. ...but I don't have much experience with custom normals so maybe somebody knows more about this.
